# decimal value in eclipse rcp text box

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have a number with decimal (something like 1256122.234589238) however swt text widget (`org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text`) is not displaying all numbers after decimal point rather it shows only 3 numbers after decimal point (like 1,256,122.235 for the above number).

I have code like this (to define the swt text):

```
textField = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false).applyTo(textField);
GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.CENTER, true, false);
gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
textField.setLayoutData(gridData);
```

Can anyone please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

You might be having some listeners which would prevent the text from being added to the text field. Please verify.

Comment: havent got any listener, getting values from database and assign with following code:
formDataBinder.bindText(this.textField, modelObject, "fieldFromModelObject");